# How do I color individual cells of a JTable based on the value in the cell?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am attempting to make a Tetris clone. The game uses a `JTable` as a representation of the board. The board is a 2D integer array.

I am trying to make it so, when a certain cell has a certain value, the cell will change to a certain color. I thought I had it working correctly, but it isn't working. I'd really appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Here is my code:

Board:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.table.*;
/**
 * @author _______________
 *
 * Board.java
 * 
 * The Board class gives information to the InitializeJTable class regarding 
 * the data-type of the JTable elements, how many rows/columns are in the JTable, etc;
 * 
 * I extended Board with AbstractTableModel, a class that allows me to display any data-type 
 * inside the elements of the JTable.
 * 
 * This class also has method declarations that are required by AbstractTableModel, these methods are:
 *      - getRowCount()
 *      - getColumnCount()
 *      - getValueAt(int, int)
 * 
 */

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Board extends AbstractTableModel {

TableColorSetter TCS;
boolean lost = false;
InitializeGUI iGUI;
InitializeJTable iJT;
public int SPEED = 1000;
L l = new L();
public Block currentBlock = l;
public int[][] boxes;//A 2D Array of booleans that defines the status of the Tetris board. Used by InitializeJTable and InitializePreviewJTable



/*
 * boardType is an integer that works with the constructor. 
 * 
 * If boardType is equal to 0, the constructor generates a 22x10 array (This is used with the main board)
 * However, if boardType is equal to 1, the constructor generates a 4x4 array (This is used with the preview/hold board, a smaller board on the side)
 */

public Board(int boardType) {

    if(boardType == 0) {
        boxes = new int[22][10];
        loop();
    } else if(boardType == 1) boxes = new int[4][4];
}

/*
 * getRowCount()
 * 
 * getRowCount is a required declaration by the AbstractTableModel class. 
 * @return          the amount of rows in the boxes boolean
 */
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return boxes.length;
}

public int getTetrisType(Block block) {
    return block.getTetrisType();
}

public void letPieceDown(int origA, int origB, int tetrisType) {
    boxes[origA][origB] = 0;
    boxes[origA + 1][origB] = tetrisType;
}

/*
 * getColumnCount()
 * 
 * getColumnCount() is a required declaration by the AbstractTableModel class. 
 * @return          the amount of columns in the boxes boolean
 */
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return boxes[0].length;
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    boxes[rowIndex][columnIndex] = (int)aValue;
    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
}

/*
 * getValueAt()
 * 
 * getValueAt() is a required declaration by the AbstractTableModel class. 
 * returns the amount of columns in the boxes boolean
 * 
 * @param   int rowIndex    The row index of the boolean that you want to return.
 *          int columnIndex The column index of the boolean that you want to return.
 * 
 * @return      the value of the boolean at the specified location in the boolean array.
 */
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return boxes[rowIndex][columnIndex];
}

public int getVal(int row, int col) {
    return boxes[row][col];
}

/**
 * 
 * loop();
 * 
 * The loop() method is a very rough draft in regards to placing Tetris objects on the board and having them move, and stack.
 * 
 * TODO: 
 */

public void loop() {

    Timer timer = new

            Timer(SPEED, new ActionListener() {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            while(lost = false) {
                for(int a = 0; a < getColumnCount(); a++) {
                    for(int b = 0; b < getRowCount(); b++) {
                        TCS.getTableCellRendererComponent(iJT.getTable(), "", false, false, b, a);
                    }
                }

            }
            if(x == getRowCount() - 1) { 
                x = 0;
            } else if(boxes[x + 1][y] != 0 && x == 0) {
                boxes[x][y] = getTetrisType(currentBlock);
                fireTableDataChanged();
                //System.out.println("GAME OVER!");
                //y++; //Just for testing.
                PlaySound sound = new PlaySound();
                sound.setSoundType(1);
                sound.start();
                ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
            } else if(boxes[x + 1][y] != 0) {
                x = 0;
            } else {
            //System.out.println("Pos: " + x + ", 0. Row count: " + getRowCount() + " -- " + x);
              letPieceDown(x, y, getTetrisType(currentBlock));
              fireTableDataChanged();
              x++;
            }
          }
      });
      timer.start();            
  }


}
```

InitializeJTable:

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;

/**
 * @author _________________
 *
 * InitializeJTable.java
 * 
 * The InitializeJTable class sets up the JTable to look like a Tetris board.
 *
 * @TODO: Add more commenting
 */

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class InitializeJTable extends JPanel {

private int COLS = 10;
private int HEIGHT = 30;
Color white = Color.WHITE;
Color black = Color.BLACK;
Board tetrisBoard;
JTable table;

public Board returnBoard() {
    return tetrisBoard;
}

public JTable getTable() {
    return table;
}

public InitializeJTable() { //The InitializeJTable constructor
    tetrisBoard = new Board(0); //Create a new board of 22x10 booleans, with a boardType of 0.
    table = new JTable(tetrisBoard); //Apply the information from the Board constructor to the JTable. (Information like, how many rows/cols in the JTable, what data-type the JTable elements are, etc)
    //setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); //Sets the Layout of the JTable to a GridBagLayout. This means, it makes the JTable look like a grid.
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false); //Disables dragging/selection of columns on the JTable with the mouse. We won't be needing that.
    TableColumnModel columns = table.getColumnModel(); //Gets information about the columns of the JTable. I need this to set the length of the columns (to make them square) 
    table.setRowHeight(HEIGHT); //Sets the height of the JTable rows to HEIGHT int, currently set to 30. Can be easily changed.
    //table.setForeground(white); //Use this to make all blocks white. Still need to make it work correctly.
    /*
     * Sadly, there isn't a -- table.setColumnHeight(int) -- method in the JTable API. (to set the length of the columns to the specified integer)
     * 
     * So I have to manually set the width of each column. This is why I declared the TableColumnModel above
     */
    for(int a = 0; a < COLS; a++) {
        columns.getColumn(a).setPreferredWidth(HEIGHT); //Sets the height of the JTable columns to HEIGHT int, currently set to 30. Can be changed easily.
    }


    add(table);//The table's all set up correctly, add it.

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please produce a minimal reproducible example and a specific question rather than a request to debug your code. See [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a relationship between the data/model and the view/table.  The model maintains the "what", the view controls the "how".

`JTable` provides a means by which you can the behaviour of the "how" (stuff gets rendered) through the use of `TableCellRenderers`, these are responsible for determining how a cell should be "painted" based on the value from the "what" from the model.

Start by having a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Now, this example uses a `double` value to determine the distance from `1` the cell value is, which represents the color (black = 0; white = 1) that the cell should be painted.  To accomplish this, it uses a custom `TableCellRenderer` which converts the value in the model (the "what") into a color (or the "how")

```
public class PaintTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, "", isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (value instanceof Double) {
            double distance = (double) value;
            int part = (int) (255 * distance);
            Color color = new Color(part, part, part);
            setBackground(color);
        } else {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        return this;
    }

}
```

[image: Smile]

It also demonstrates a couple of other things you might need to know about the `JTable` as well.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class Smile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Smile();
    }

    public Smile() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private double[][] smily = {
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.996, 1, 0.843, 0.784, 0.788, 0.773, 0.769, 0.765, 0.765, 0.788, 0.784, 0.847, 1, 0.996, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.996},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.871, 0.733, 0.761, 0.847, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.933, 0.843, 0.761, 0.733, 0.871, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 0.784, 0.733, 0.902, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.898, 0.733, 0.784, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 0.765, 0.773, 0.945, 0.945, 0.941, 0.929, 0.937, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.941, 0.957, 0.91, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.78, 0.761, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 0.808, 0.773, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.294, 0.447, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.702, 0.239, 0.886, 0.941, 0.945, 0.941, 0.78, 0.8, 1, 1},
            {1, 0.89, 0.725, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.843, 0, 0, 0.922, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.408, 0, 0.663, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.941, 0.725, 0.89, 1},
            {0.992, 0.753, 0.902, 0.941, 0.945, 0.945, 0.941, 0.725, 0.051, 0, 0.808, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.294, 0.051, 0.553, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.91, 0.741, 0.984},
            {0.871, 0.78, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.945, 0.941, 0.694, 0.051, 0, 0.784, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.278, 0, 0.518, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.78, 0.878},
            {0.816, 0.855, 0.941, 0.945, 0.945, 0.945, 0.941, 0.737, 0, 0.051, 0.82, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.302, 0.051, 0.565, 0.941, 0.949, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.863, 0.804},
            {0.8, 0.945, 0.941, 0.945, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.875, 0, 0, 0.937, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.443, 0, 0.694, 0.945, 0.945, 0.945, 0.945, 0.949, 0.941, 0.765},
            {0.769, 0.941, 0.945, 0.957, 0.961, 0.941, 0.945, 0.941, 0.443, 0.565, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.769, 0.388, 0.918, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.78},
            {0.753, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.953, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.788},
            {0.741, 0.945, 0.839, 0.427, 0.624, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.949, 0.945, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.6, 0.376, 0.941, 0.945, 0.784},
            {0.749, 0.941, 0.914, 0.345, 0.647, 0.941, 0.945, 0.949, 0.945, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.941, 0.945, 0.945, 0.945, 0.945, 0.941, 0.702, 0.384, 0.941, 0.941, 0.78},
            {0.796, 0.945, 0.941, 0.627, 0.592, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.945, 0.945, 0.941, 0.949, 0.945, 0.941, 0.945, 0.945, 0.937, 0.945, 0.58, 0.631, 0.941, 0.937, 0.776},
            {0.812, 0.859, 0.941, 0.855, 0.384, 0.957, 0.941, 0.945, 0.945, 0.945, 0.941, 0.953, 0.941, 0.945, 0.945, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.384, 0.941, 0.941, 0.867, 0.812},
            {0.871, 0.788, 0.941, 0.941, 0.533, 0.51, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.949, 0.945, 0.945, 0.945, 0.941, 0.937, 0.941, 0.945, 0.522, 0.522, 0.941, 0.941, 0.792, 0.886},
            {0.992, 0.761, 0.914, 0.941, 0.941, 0.325, 0.612, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.624, 0.318, 0.941, 0.945, 0.91, 0.765, 0.988},
            {1, 0.882, 0.741, 0.941, 0.941, 0.922, 0.337, 0.475, 0.894, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.894, 0.49, 0.325, 0.925, 0.941, 0.941, 0.753, 0.894, 1},
            {1, 1, 0.796, 0.78, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.592, 0.447, 0.565, 0.667, 0.737, 0.737, 0.667, 0.565, 0.451, 0.588, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.796, 0.808, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 0.996, 0.753, 0.788, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.702, 0.584, 0.557, 0.553, 0.592, 0.698, 0.906, 0.941, 0.945, 0.941, 0.796, 0.769, 0.996, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 0.769, 0.745, 0.922, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.918, 0.741, 0.776, 1, 1, 0.996, 1},
            {1, 0.996, 1, 1, 1, 0.851, 0.733, 0.773, 0.867, 0.945, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.941, 0.945, 0.867, 0.769, 0.725, 0.851, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.984, 0.843, 0.78, 0.761, 0.78, 0.796, 0.796, 0.784, 0.765, 0.78, 0.835, 0.984, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
        };

        public TestPane() {
            AsciiTableModel model = new AsciiTableModel();
            model.setData(smily);

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.setRowHeight(24);
            Enumeration<TableColumn> columns = table.getColumnModel().getColumns();
            while (columns.hasMoreElements()) {
                TableColumn col = columns.nextElement();
                col.setWidth(24);
                col.setPreferredWidth(24);
                col.setMinWidth(24);
                col.setMaxWidth(24);
            }
            table.setRowHeight(24);
            table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new PaintTableCellRenderer());

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public class PaintTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, "", isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (value instanceof Double) {
                double distance = (double) value;
                int part = (int) (255 * distance);
                Color color = new Color(part, part, part);
                setBackground(color);
            } else {
                setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            return this;
        }

    }

    public class AsciiTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private double[][] data;

        public AsciiTableModel() {
            data = new double[24][24];
        }

        public void setData(double[][] value) {
            data = value;
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 24;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 24;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }

    }

}
```

I had intended to provide a "sad" face which you could switch between, but my daughter wanted me to go paint with her, sorry ;)

Comment: How long did it take you to get that data just right?

Comment: @peeskillet Oddly, not very long, google "smiley", downloaded image, scaled down, convert to gray scale and then wrote a little converter to write the data out...not long at all :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you so so so much! I got it working using your examples of PaintTableCellRenderer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom table cell renderer. [Here's a good place to start](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Tablewithacustomcellrendererandeditorforthecolordata.htm)

Comment: The Swing tutorial on [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) is a better place to start. This is where the code you linked to was taken from. The tutorial provides explanations about the code rather that just a code dump.

Comment: @camickr I've been reading up on Custom Renderers, but I have no idea how (or where) I would put this code. I'm just really lost. This is really over my head, honestly.

Comment: Forget about your game. Create a simple example to help you understand the concept of how a renderer works. Create a simple table, maybe a table with 3 rows and columns. with static data. Randomly assign numbers to each of the cells. Then create a custom renderer that colors even number cells with one color and odd number cells with another color. This is a much simpler problem to solve. All the code you posted with Timers and custom TableModel is unrelated to the rendering concept. So simplify the problem to learn how renderers work. Then you can post that code and we can help.