# Use custom JTableCellRenderes

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable with 6 columns. When adding a row to the table I need to add black color for the last cell in fist row. red color for second row. The corresponding color comes from a different method. This is my custom table cell renderer.

```
class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column, Color color)
    {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        label.setBackground(color);
        return label;
    }
}
```

This is how I used it when adding a table row.

```
  private void addTableRow(String type, String name, String rank, String notes, String location, Color color)
    {
        boolean isExport = isExportEnable();
        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]
        {
            type,
            name,
            rank,
            notes,
            location,
            isExport
        }
        );
        for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); ++i)
        {
            JTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setCellRenderer((TableCellRenderer) new CustomRenderer().getTableCellRendererComponent(null, null, false, false, i, 6, color));
        }
    }
```

When I add the fist row it gets the correct color. But when I add the second row both first and second color cell fills with the second color. How can I get the exact row. **Actually what I want is to fill the last cell of each row with a different color while adding a row.**

Comment: *"Although I posted this question earlier I did not get the exact answer."* What makes you think this one will get a different answer? Is it different in some way? Either way, you should [edit] an existing question rather than start a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go have a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Using Custom Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) because you clearly don't understand how renderers work in Swing.

You NEVER add a component to a `JTable`'s `TableModel`, that's not it's responsibility.

You configure the `JTable`'s `TableColumn`s to use specific renders, something like...

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer);
```

assuming you want a specific renderer for a specific column and not have it configured for a type of object

Comment: I got the solution but then faced to a different one. Changed the question with the correct solution and the new problem.

Comment: I am still struggling with the above question so can anyone help?

Comment: *"Actually what I want is to fill the last cell of each row with a different color while adding a row"* - Not really how it works.  A column has a single render.  What you need to do is seed the value of the cell with the color you want to use, then have the renderer change based on that value

Comment: Could you please show me an example?

Comment: [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552644/how-do-i-color-individual-cells-of-a-jtable-based-on-the-value-in-the-cell/30553979#30553979)?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it did not work. Can I fill the color while adding the row instead of filling the cell after adding the row?

Comment: You have ONE cell renderer for each column. It takes data from the table model and "renderers" it the way you want to - this is how it works. So, you need to see the information you want into the row/column so that the render knows what to do with it

Comment: Still struggling. Can you please explain using my scenario?

Comment: Thanks. Finaly I made a solution I added colorInCellRenderer.setCellColor(tableModel.getRowCount() - 1, 6, color);
JTable.repaint(); when adding a row. Now I have another problem I want to delete it when 'Delete' button is clicked. Is there any method to do that?